# Check/uncheck checkbox in a row programmatically

Tags: wpf, vb.net, devexpress

How would I check/uncheck checkbox in a row programmatically?

I have this gridcontrol which I can populate and I can set focused row handle on item I want but I do not know how to check a checkbox in a row programmatically.

This is my gridcontrol:

```
<dxg:GridControl KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" AutoGenerateColumns="none"  x:Name="gridOtpremnice"  SelectionMode="MultipleRow" IsTabStop="False" Margin="10,79,10,51" BandGeneratorTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource ControlStyle1}">          
  <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="obvFr" Header="Obveza FR" IsSmart="True" BestFitMode="VisibleRows" AllowBestFit="True" Width="150" Fixed="left" BestFitArea="Rows"/>
  <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="fiscBr" Header="Broj FR" IsSmart="True" BestFitMode="VisibleRows" AllowBestFit="True" Width="150" Fixed="left" BestFitArea="Rows"/>
  <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="broj" Header="Broj" IsSmart="True" BestFitMode="VisibleRows" AllowBestFit="True" Width="60" Fixed="right" BestFitArea="Rows" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="0"/>
  <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="dat" Header="Datum" IsSmart="True" BestFitMode="VisibleRows" AllowBestFit="True" Width="50" Fixed="right" BestFitArea="Rows"/>
  <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="iznos" Header="Iznos" IsSmart="True" BestFitMode="VisibleRows" AllowBestFit="True"  Width="50" Fixed="right" BestFitArea="Rows" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Right">                
  </dxg:GridColumn>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

And this is how I set a focused row handle:

```
Dim rowHandle As Integer = gridOtpremnice.DataController.FindRowByValue("broj", otpremnica)
If gridOtpremnice.IsValidRowHandle(rowHandle) Then
    gridOtpremnice.View.FocusedRowHandle = rowHandle
End If
```

How would I check a checkbox in selected row programmatically?

Comment: If you're using proper binding, you need only change the source data.  The grid reacts to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for this

```
Gridview.SetRowCellValue(Gridview.FocusedRowHandle, Gridview.Columns(column_id), True)
```

or

```
 Gridview.SetRowCellValue(Gridview.FocusedRowHandle, Gridview.Columns(column_id), False)
```